# How can I swap the usage of the 'fn' key for my Razer Blackwidow on OSX?

Tags: macos, drivers, razer-keyboard

I just bought the Razer Blackwidow 2013 keyboard, and after installing drivers (Synapse 2.0) I run into a strange issue:

My function keys started to work very strange. They started to use their "shortcuts" (not sure how to properly name it) without the need to tap <kbd>fn</kbd> key + function key.

For example: <kbd>F9</kbd> starts Macro recording instead of MissionControl. And now to achieve default behavior I need to press <kbd>fn</kbd> key with function keys.

Without drivers, function keys work fine (<kbd>F9</kbd> for MissionControl etc). Also I can tap <kbd>fn</kbd> key + a function key to use a shortcut: turn sound on/off, stop/play music etc. But without drivers I can't use on the fly macro recording, which is why I decided to install Synapse.

If I turn on "Gaming Mode" everything works as expected. Functional keys behavior is default. And if I tap <kbd>fn</kbd> + function key shortcuts works fine.

My question is: is there a workaround to get default functionality without the need to use "Gaming Mode"? Because for now everything seems to work "inside out".

Comment: As a user of this keyboard what you describe sounds like normal behavior.

Comment: Normal behavior = everything works as described in the user guide (you should press the fn key to use functional keys shortcuts). But for me all shortcuts work without the fn key. Only when I turn game mode on all works fine.

Comment: You sure you turning game mode on instead perhaps turning it off?

Comment: 100% sure. Because when gaming mode is turned on I see green G on the top right corner of the keyboard. BTW in the Windows 7 all things work as expected, and it's not necessary to turn gaming mode on to get default behavior of functional keys.

Comment: i'm also affected by this. synapse is a horribly broken software. I installed it for mapping the M1-5 keys, at first they were working but now they stopped working too. and i too have to enable gaming mood for normal operation of F keys :|

Answer (score -2):

I have the same issue on OSX. I think the problem isn't related to the keyboard or synapse but to OSX. Indeed, on a MAC functions keys use the "shortcuts" (lights, volume) without fn pressed. 
You should try to go in System Settings, keyboard and then select "Use F1, F2 as standard function key"